# R go back 3 months, always month end last day

Tags: r, date

I am trying to get 3 month back, and tried many different solutions posted here. The one that generally works fine is `dt %m+% months(-3)` from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14169620/add-a-month-to-a-date/14182326#14182326). however, it is not working well again for this month. I wonder if there is a ultimate final working fine solution.

```
dt_1   <- as.Date("2018-06-30")
dt_2   <- as.character(dt_1 %m+% months(-3))
```

dt_2 became "2018-03-30" instead of "2018-03-31".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `floor_date` to get to the first day of your input month, then subtract 2 months and 1 day.

```
library(lubridate)

dt_1  <- as.Date("2018-06-30")
as.character(floor_date(dt_1, 'month') - months(2) - 1)

#[1] "2018-03-31"
```