# Enter a month and get the 1st and last day for it in the particular year

Tags: r, date

Is there a way in R to get the 1st and the last day for a specified month.
Eg.

```
Input: September 2018 or any other format to specify month and year
Expected output:
1st day function (Input) -> 01-Sep-2018 or any other valid date format
Last day function (Input) -> 30-Sep-2018 or any other valid date format
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create a function in base R

```
get_first_and_last_date <- function(month_year) {
   start_date = as.Date(paste0("01 ", month_year), "%d %b %Y")
   end_date = (seq(start_date, length.out = 2, by = "month") - 1)[2]
   c(start_date, end_date)
}

get_first_and_last_date('Dec 2018')
#[1] "2018-12-01" "2018-12-31"

get_first_and_last_date('Sep 2016')
#[1] "2016-09-01" "2016-09-30"
```

Whatever format you enter make sure it is consistent throughout. Here I have considered the input would always be a month name and complete year.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `lubridate` library:

```
require(lubridate)
d <- as.Date('2018-09-01')
last_day <- d
day(last_day) <- days_in_month(last_day)
```

For a base R solution, we can define a helper method to add months.  Then, the last day of a given month can be computed by adding one month to the first of the month and subtracting one day:

```
add.months <- function(date, n) seq(date, by=paste (n, "months"), length=2 [2]
d <- as.Date('2018-09-01')         # first of the month
last_day <- add.months(d, 1) - 1   # last of the month
```

Credit for the `add.months` helper function is given to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14169620/add-a-month-to-a-date).