# How do I insert a new function into my R package?

Tags: r

I made a package in R using these [instructions](http://web.mit.edu/insong/www/pdf/rpackage_instructions.pdf). I use RStudio and I'd like to add a new function to the package.

Do I just put the functions into an R script and drag it into the folder in the package called R? If I do that, do I need to change the contents of the folder named man?

Comment: You might find this guide a bit easier to follow, I certainly did: http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz

Answer (score 8):

Say you have written a new function called `my_function`

```
my_function <- function(){
  print("New function!")
}
```

You need to document it in the same R file. So your complete R file would look something like this

```
#' my_function
#' 
#' A function to print the words "New function!"
#'
#' @return A character vector
#' @export
#'
#' @examples
#' my_function()

my_function <- function(){
  print("New function!")
}
```

Now save this file in your R/ directory in the package

Run `devtools::document()` and that will update your man/ directory.

You have now added a new function to your package

In my opinion, the book [R Packages](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/) is the best guide. You can read it for free at that link