# Filtering the data w.r.t maximum date and extracting last 3 months data

Tags: r, filter

I am trying to filter last 3 months data in R w.r.t maximum date present in my date column.

I initially added a column to my existing data frame and used the below expression for filtering the data. I want to eliminate this extra step and do the filtering directly.

```
last_three_month <- df_1[date_format > max(as.Date(date_format)) %m-% months(4) & 
                         date_format <= max(date_format) , ]
```

When I use `df_1[MonthYear]` and filter the data I see an error like

> "Error: ‘max’ not meaningful for factors"

Data

```
MonthYear   Number    Risk 
1/18/2019   101      High AESI
1/18/2019   905 
1/18/2019   909 
1/18/2019   904 
2/18/2019   101      High AESI
2/18/2019   905 
2/18/2019   904 
2/18/2019   909 
2/18/2019   907 
2/18/2019   541      High AESI
2/18/2019   908      High AESI
2/18/2019   906      High AESI
2/18/2019   046 
2/18/2019   018      High AESI
2/18/2019   019 
2/18/2019   002      High AESI
3/18/2019   904 
3/18/2019   907 
3/18/2019   905
```

Code

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
library(reshape)

Input <- read.csv("C:/Users/Documents/Exports/HR.csv")
Output <- Input #%>% filter(Year == 2019)
df_output <- as.data.frame(Output)
date_format <- as.Date(paste("01-", df_output$Month.Year, sep = ""), 
                       format = "%d-%b-%y")
df_1 <- cbind(df_output, date_format)

last_three_month <- df_1[date_format > max(as.Date(date_format)) %m-% months(4) &
                         date_format <= max(date_format) , ]
```

I am actually trying to filter data directly in the data frame rather than adding one more column and achieving it.  Can you please advise - Thanks

Comment: Your date conversion is unclear. Are those not 2019 dates in format `M/D/YYYY`?

Comment: Hi - They are 2019 Dates from Jan to March.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using `seq()` as shown by @G. Grothendieck's [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5226089/1422451) to retrieve the date of three months ago from max *MonthYear*.

**Data** *(some dates converted to 2018 for demonstration of three month filter)*

```
txt <- 'MonthYear   Number    Risk 
"1/18/2018"   101      "High AESI"
"1/18/2018"   905      NA
"1/18/2019"   909      NA
"1/18/2019"   904      NA 
"2/18/2018"   101      "High AESI"
"2/18/2018"   905      NA 
"2/18/2019"   904      NA 
"2/18/2019"   909      NA 
"2/18/2019"   907      NA 
"2/18/2019"   541      "High AESI"
"2/18/2019"   908      "High AESI"
"2/18/2019"   906      "High AESI"
"2/18/2019"   046      NA 
"2/18/2019"   018      "High AESI"
"2/18/2019"   019      NA 
"2/18/2019"   002      "High AESI"
"3/18/2018"   904      NA 
"3/18/2019"   907      NA 
"3/18/2019"   905      NA '

Input <- read.table(text=txt, header=TRUE)
```

**Code**

```
# CONVERT TO DATE
Input$MonthYear <- as.Date(Input$MonthYear, format = "%m/%d/%Y")

# SUBSET DATA
last_three_month_df <- subset(Input, MonthYear > seq(as.Date(max(MonthYear)), length=2, by="-3 months")[2] &
                                     MonthYear <= max(MonthYear))    

last_three_month_df 
#     MonthYear Number      Risk
# 3  2019-01-18    909      <NA>
# 4  2019-01-18    904      <NA>
# 7  2019-02-18    904      <NA>
# 8  2019-02-18    909      <NA>
# 9  2019-02-18    907      <NA>
# 10 2019-02-18    541 High AESI
# 11 2019-02-18    908 High AESI
# 12 2019-02-18    906 High AESI
# 13 2019-02-18     46      <NA>
# 14 2019-02-18     18 High AESI
# 15 2019-02-18     19      <NA>
# 16 2019-02-18      2 High AESI
# 18 2019-03-18    907      <NA>
# 19 2019-03-18    905      <NA>
```

Answer (score 1):

`read.csv` imports strings (such as `"1/18/2019"`) as 'factor' columns by default. This categorical data class is not a 'Date'. Instead use `readr::read_csv` which will probably detect that your date column is a date, and should then allow your code to run as you expect. If you use the RStudio import wizard with the *readr* option, you can manually select the column types and the corresponding code will be created for you.