# Getting a date few months back from the current date in R

Tags: r

Please do not close this question as it is not a duplicate of [How to subtract months from a date in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5225823/how-to-subtract-months-from-a-date-in-r)
I am trying to convert a date of type `IDate` to `mondate` and then back to `IDate`.

In the code below I am trying to get a date 6 months prior to the given date `date1`, which is IDate object.

```
library(mondate)
date1 = as.IDate("2020-02-10")
date2 = as.IDate(mondate(date1)-6)
```

However, I am getting the warning

```
Warning message:
Attempting to convert class 'IDateDate' to 'mondate' via 'as.Date' then 'as.numeric'. Check results!
```

Can someone tell me how to correct this warning?

**Solution -**
As suggested by Ronak in comments - `date1 %m-% months(6)` works just fine with IDate class.

Comment: With `lubridate` you can do `date1 %m-% months(6)`. There is also an option with `mondate` in linked post.

Comment: I am using the ```mondate``` library to get 6 months prior date and getting warning while converting it to ```IDate```. I could not find any help in the linked post on this issue.

Comment: ```date1 %m-% months(6)``` did worked out fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IDate` isn't a very common type of Date class hence `mondate` returns you a warning to check the results and make sure it is correct since it has internally converted `IDate` to date class.

```
library(mondate)
mondate(date1) - 6

#mondate: timeunits="months"
#[1] 08/11/2019
```

> Warning message:
> Attempting to convert class 'IDateDate' to 'mondate' via 'as.Date' then 'as.numeric'. Check results!

This is a friendly warning and can be ignored. If you don't want the warning convert to Date class explicitly.

```
mondate(as.Date(date1)) - 6
#mondate: timeunits="months"
#[1] 08/11/2019
```

---

Using `lubridate`'s `%m-%` works fine with `IDate` as well as Date class.

```
library(lubridate)

date1 %m-% months(6)
#[1] "2019-08-10"
as.Date(date1) %m-% months(6)
#[1] "2019-08-10"
```