# How to subtract using max(date) and second latest (month) date

Tags: r, date, max, subset

I'm trying to create a new variable which equals the latest month's value minus the previous month's (or 3 months prior, etc.).

A quick df:

```
country <- c("XYZ", "XYZ", "XYZ")
my_dates <- c("2021-10-01", "2021-09-01", "2021-08-01")
var1 <- c(1, 2, 3)
df1 <- country %>% cbind(my_dates) %>% cbind(var1) %>% as.data.frame()
df1$my_dates <- as.Date(df1$my_dates)
df1$var1 <- as.numeric(df1$var1)
```

For example, I've tried (partially from: [How to subtract months from a date in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5225823/how-to-subtract-months-from-a-date-in-r/5226089))

```
library(tidyverse)
df2 <- df1 %>%
 mutate(dif_1month = var1[my_dates==max(my_dates)] -var1[my_dates==max(my_dates) %m-% months(1)]
```

I've also tried different variations of using lag():

```
df2 <- df1 %>%
 mutate(dif_1month = var1[my_dates==max(my_dates)] - var1[my_dates==max(my_dates)-lag(max(my_dates), n=1L)])
```

Any suggestions on how to grab the value of a variable when dates equal the second latest observation?

Thanks for help, and apologies for not including any data. Can edit if necessary.

**Edited with a few potential answers:**

#this gives me the value of var1 of the latest date

```
df2 <- df1 %>% 
  mutate(value_1month = var1[my_dates==max(my_dates)])
```

#this gives me the date of the second latest date

```
df2 <- df1 %>% 
  mutate(month1 = max(my_dates) %m-%months(1))
```

#This gives me the second to latest value

```
df2 <- df1 %>% 
  mutate(var1_1month = var1[my_dates==max(my_dates) %m-%months(1)])
```

#This gives me the difference of the latest value and the second to last of var1

```
df2 <- df1 %>% 
  mutate(diff_1month = var1[my_dates==max(my_dates)] - var1[my_dates==max(my_dates) %m-%months(1)])
```

Answer (score 1):

`mutate` requires the output to be of the same `length` as the number of rows of the original data.  When we do the subsetting, the length is different.  We may need `ifelse` or `case_when`

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df1 %>%
    mutate(diff_1month = case_when(my_dates==max(my_dates) ~ 
           my_dates %m-% months(1)))
```

NOTE: Without a reproducible example, it is not clear about the column types and values

---

Based on the OP's update, we may do an `arrange` first, grab the last two 'val' and get the `diff`erence

```
df1 %>% 
  arrange(my_dates) %>%
  mutate(dif_1month = diff(tail(var1, 2)))
    .   my_dates var1 dif_1month
1 XYZ 2021-08-01    3         -1
2 XYZ 2021-09-01    2         -1
3 XYZ 2021-10-01    1         -1
```