# How to obtain ages IN MONTHS from birthdates?

Tags: r, date, datetime, lubridate

I have a column of birthdates from my participants and I need to get their **ages measured in *months***. I'm wondering if there's an automatic way to do that **accounting for** facts such as that months have different number of days and years vary in number of days as well (among others) ? What I mean is: I know I can set a random 30 or 31 to months or 365 or 366 to years, but **I'm wondering if is there a way to make R get the ACTUAL dates**, as such  `Sys.Date()` does, so that I could be more precise about that. This is what I haven't seen in the other questions [EDITED]

- data:

```
head(data)
  ID      BIRTH YEAR
1  A 23/04/2009 2009
2  B 24/03/2010 2010
3  C 28/12/2009 2009
```

- I need to **obtain participant's ages in months from a specific date**. Let's say from their birth until 31/08/2020, for example (note: dates are in the Brazilian notation DAY/MONTH/YEAR). Any ideas?

I've seen many interesting posts, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5225823/how-to-subtract-months-from-a-date-in-r), but they didn't quite solve what I need, hence I hope this is not a duplicate. I've also seen some suggestions such as `difftime("23/04/2009", "31/08/2020", units = 'weeks')` , but it doesn't work for months.

- data:

```
> dput(data)
structure(list(ID = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", 
"I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U"
), BIRTH = c("23/04/2009", "24/03/2010", "28/12/2009", "19/08/2009", 
"02/12/2009", "12/05/2010", "26/02/2010", "07/10/2009", "22/04/2010", 
"01/04/2010", "31/03/2010", "27/01/2010", "23/09/2009", "28/09/2009", 
"28/10/2009", "21/06/2009", "28/10/2009", "19/08/2009", "10/09/2009", 
"13/07/2009", "22/09/2009"), YEAR = c("2009", "2010", "2009", 
"2009", "2009", "2010", "2010", "2009", "2010", "2010", "2010", 
"2010", "2009", "2009", "2009", "2009", "2009", "2009", "2009", 
"2009", "2009")), row.names = c(NA, -21L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Maybe this answer worth for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995933/number-of-months-between-two-dates

Comment: Oh, I've seen that post before too, forgot to add to my post. Yeah, that was the closer I got, but still I couldn't get my head around to use that to solve my problem @juanbarq

Answer (score 1):

First be sure both of your dates are in date format (one option is to use `lubridate`s `dmy` function).
Having date formats we could do maths, meaning to substract one date from the other. The trick is to wrap the whole thing around `as.numeric` to get numeric class. By the way to get month from days we have to divide by 365/12:

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
  mutate(Age_in_Months = as.numeric(dmy("31/08/2020") - dmy(BIRTH)) / 365/12)
```

```
  ID      BIRTH YEAR Age_in_Months
1   A 23/04/2009 2009     0.9470320
2   B 24/03/2010 2010     0.8705479
3   C 28/12/2009 2009     0.8901826
4   D 19/08/2009 2009     0.9200913
5   E 02/12/2009 2009     0.8961187
6   F 12/05/2010 2010     0.8593607
7   G 26/02/2010 2010     0.8764840
8   H 07/10/2009 2009     0.9089041
9   I 22/04/2010 2010     0.8639269
10  J 01/04/2010 2010     0.8687215
11  K 31/03/2010 2010     0.8689498
12  L 27/01/2010 2010     0.8833333
13  M 23/09/2009 2009     0.9121005
14  N 28/09/2009 2009     0.9109589
15  O 28/10/2009 2009     0.9041096
16  P 21/06/2009 2009     0.9335616
17  Q 28/10/2009 2009     0.9041096
18  R 19/08/2009 2009     0.9200913
19  S 10/09/2009 2009     0.9150685
20  T 13/07/2009 2009     0.9285388
21  U 22/09/2009 2009     0.9123288
```

Comment: @TarJee, hi, thanks, I almost got that. I'm struggling to understand this part: ```asnumeric(dmy("31/08/2020"))``` which equals 18505. What does this number mean?

Comment: Dates could be explained in different ways. One is: integer in days from "1970-01-01" is used. See this example: `library(lubridate) as_date(1)` will give `[1] "1970-01-02"` One day plus 1970-01-01. `as_date(10)` will give: `[1] "1970-01-11"` e.g. 10 days plus 1970-01-01. And finally `as_date(18505)` will give: 1] "2020-08-31". Both are the same with the difference that in numeric form you could do calculations. Therefore I use lubridate because for me it is easier to think of dates!

Comment: There is something wrong here as all 'age in month' values are between 0 and 1.

Comment: You are right. Hmmh will check when  I am on my desktop. thx. do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Using the functions from [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995933/number-of-months-between-two-dates) you can proceed to calculate your ages difference in months like you can see in Dif_months1. For more accurate you can use `interval` from `lubridate`, see Dif_months2:

```
library(lubridate)
data <- structure(list(ID = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", 
                      "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U"
), BIRTH = as.Date(c("23/04/2009", "24/03/2010", "28/12/2009", "19/08/2009", 
             "02/12/2009", "12/05/2010", "26/02/2010", "07/10/2009", "22/04/2010", 
             "01/04/2010", "31/03/2010", "27/01/2010", "23/09/2009", "28/09/2009", 
             "28/10/2009", "21/06/2009", "28/10/2009", "19/08/2009", "10/09/2009", 
             "13/07/2009", "22/09/2009"), format="%d/%m/%Y"), YEAR = c("2009", "2010", "2009", 
                                                   "2009", "2009", "2010", "2010", "2009", "2010", "2010", "2010", 
                                                   "2010", "2009", "2009", "2009", "2009", "2009", "2009", "2009", 
                                                   "2009", "2009")), row.names = c(NA, -21L), class = "data.frame")

# turn a date into a 'monthnumber' relative to an origin
monnb <- function(d) { lt <- as.POSIXlt(as.Date(d, origin="1900-01-01")); lt$year*12 + lt$mon } 
# compute a month difference as a difference between two monnb's
mondf <- function(d1, d2) { monnb(d2) - monnb(d1) }

data %>% mutate(Dif_months1 = mondf(BIRTH, Sys.Date()), 
                Dif_months2 = interval(BIRTH, Sys.Date()) %/% days(1) / (365/12))
```

Note that I format your original dates with `format="%d/%m/%Y"`

Output:

```
   ID      BIRTH YEAR Dif_months Dif_months2
1   A 2009-04-23 2009        165    165.3370
2   B 2010-03-24 2010        154    154.3233
3   C 2009-12-28 2009        157    157.1507
4   D 2009-08-19 2009        161    161.4575
5   E 2009-12-02 2009        157    158.0055
6   F 2010-05-12 2010        152    152.7123
7   G 2010-02-26 2010        155    155.1781
8   H 2009-10-07 2009        159    159.8466
9   I 2010-04-22 2010        153    153.3699
10  J 2010-04-01 2010        153    154.0603
11  K 2010-03-31 2010        154    154.0932
12  L 2010-01-27 2010        156    156.1644
13  M 2009-09-23 2009        160    160.3068
14  N 2009-09-28 2009        160    160.1425
15  O 2009-10-28 2009        159    159.1562
16  P 2009-06-21 2009        163    163.3973
17  Q 2009-10-28 2009        159    159.1562
18  R 2009-08-19 2009        161    161.4575
19  S 2009-09-10 2009        160    160.7342
20  T 2009-07-13 2009        162    162.6740
21  U 2009-09-22 2009        160    160.3397
```

Comment: hi, thanks :) I saw that answer in the original post before, but I didn't quite got that. I didn't get what 'monnb' is actually doing since we have to set an arbitrary origin to it. It calculates anything from '1900-01-01' ? or it's just there to have the correct date format? and when we do ```days(1) / (365/12)``` we're kinda 'arbitraly' defining 30 as a month, right?

Comment: Hi @larissa-cury! The origin paremeter it´s optional in `as.Date`, you can use `as.Date(d)` and work the same. Well, with  `(365/12)` you are estimating each month 30,41 days

Answer (score 1):

As you noted, `difftime()` does not work for "month" as it is not possible to give a "definite" answer: one could divide by 30, or 31, or use days in the year accounding for leap years or not and so on.

Otherwise, you problem is a two-liner.  Assume your data is in data.frame `D`:

```
D <- within(D, bd <- as.Date(BIRTH, "%d/%m/%Y")) 
D <- within(D, dm <- as.numeric(difftime(as.Date("2020-08-31"), bd))/30)
```

where we first parse as a `Date` and then use `difftime` and scaling an (arbitrarily chose) 30 days per months.  This gets us an expanded data.frame:

```
> D
   ID      BIRTH YEAR         bd      dm
1   A 23/04/2009 2009 2009-04-23 138.267
2   B 24/03/2010 2010 2010-03-24 127.100
3   C 28/12/2009 2009 2009-12-28 129.967
4   D 19/08/2009 2009 2009-08-19 134.333
5   E 02/12/2009 2009 2009-12-02 130.833
6   F 12/05/2010 2010 2010-05-12 125.467
7   G 26/02/2010 2010 2010-02-26 127.967
8   H 07/10/2009 2009 2009-10-07 132.700
9   I 22/04/2010 2010 2010-04-22 126.133
10  J 01/04/2010 2010 2010-04-01 126.833
11  K 31/03/2010 2010 2010-03-31 126.867
12  L 27/01/2010 2010 2010-01-27 128.967
13  M 23/09/2009 2009 2009-09-23 133.167
14  N 28/09/2009 2009 2009-09-28 133.000
15  O 28/10/2009 2009 2009-10-28 132.000
16  P 21/06/2009 2009 2009-06-21 136.300
17  Q 28/10/2009 2009 2009-10-28 132.000
18  R 19/08/2009 2009 2009-08-19 134.333
19  S 10/09/2009 2009 2009-09-10 133.600
20  T 13/07/2009 2009 2009-07-13 135.567
21  U 22/09/2009 2009 2009-09-22 133.200
>
```

You could also replace `BIRTH`, of course, or just use vectors. I like keeping the data together. You could make the reference data a function argument for a helper function if you desire.

No other packages needed for the two-liner.  And, if you wanted to, a one-liner also works where the reference date is still the one parameter used besides the input data:

```
D <- within(D, dm <- as.numeric(difftime(as.Date("2020-08-31"),
        as.Date(BIRTH, "%d/%m/%Y"))/30))
```

(which I broke over two lines for the display but is really just one).

Comment: Hi, @Dirk Eddelbuettel , thanks,  So, this was my first choice, but I'm trying to avoid having to choose arbitraly between 30, 31 or 29 days per month and I couldn't run the second line of the code: ```Error in UseMethod("within") : 
  no applicable method for 'within' applied to an object of class "function"```

Comment: I copied and pasted from a worked example. You cam also reduce it to _one_ line if you first assign your data to `D`.  The it is `D <- within(D, dm <- as.numeric(difftime(as.Date("2020-08-31"), as.Date(BIRTH, "%d/%m/%Y"))/30))` which is the same as before but skips an _explicit_ conversion of `BIRTH`. Ensure you have a data.frame with the correct name, and ensure you use a `<-` inside `within`.